# Событие отрабатывающее после добавления элемента инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Имеется:
Новая, чистая установка Битрикс. Лицензия Бизнес.

Задача: при создании элемента инфоблока - посылать запрос на другой сайт, а тот в свою очередь будет проверять список элементов, который выводится с помощью RSS. С этим проблем нет, кроме одной загвоздки: детальная картинка. Или анонсовая. Или любые другие файлы.

Проблема:
Для отправки запроса использую событие onAfterIBlockElementAdd и через обработчик, в `init.php` описываю действие:

```
AddEventHandler( "iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd", Array( "addElementToBackend ", "OnAfterIBlockElementAddHandler" ) );


class addElementToBackend {
    function OnAfterIBlockElementAddHandler($arFields) {
        if ($arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 1) {

            $url = "http://blabla.bla/bla?action=bla";
            $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method'  => 'GET',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                )
            )));

            if ($result) {
                // действие
            } else {
                // действие
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Запрос отправляется. Тот сайт проверяет страницу с RSS, и получает последний элемент. Но без детальной картинки. Потому что OnAfterIBlockElementAdd возвращает массив с временными файлами. В админке, само собой, тоже детальное изображение не найдено.

При этом, если добавляю следующий элемент - то у предыдущего всё появляется. То есть фактически детальное изображение есть, но почему-то не прикрепляется к элементу ИБ в момент его создания, а только после создания следующего.

По ощущениям, как будто не срабатывает какое-то последнее действие в `OnAfterIBlockElementAdd`.

Вопрос: решаемо ли это? потому что подобный вопрос уже обсуждался на форуме битрикс. И ещё: есть ли событие которое срабатывает после того как весь элемент полностью добавлен в базу со всеми конечными данными?

Comment: Есть событие `OnIBlockElementAdd`

Comment: @NikolajSarry на момент срабатывания `OnIBlockElementAdd` элемент ещё не добавлен в базу.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в `file_get_contents`. 
В данном случае, мне не было принципиально получать ответ сервера, поэтому я использовал cURL и ограничил время ожидания ответа. 
Но это всё-таки костыль.